# my thread split dosent work fast enough in python

Tags: python, multithreading, scikit-learn, histogram

**i am trying to make my hog traslation faster but it seems that the more threads i adding the slower it gets help??**

```
def worker(patches):
    return [feature.hog(patch) for patch in patches]
```

that the function

```
segment_split, segment_index, threads = 4, 0, []
segment_jump = len(patches) / segment_split
segment_list = []
for i in range(segment_split):
    segment_list.append(patches[int(segment_index):int(segment_index+segment_jump)])
    segment_index += segment_jump

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
lis = pool.map(worker, segment_list)
tmp = []
for x in lis:
    tmp.extend(x)
```

Comment: Threads are for concurrency, not parallelism. Python can only run _one_ thread at a time because of the Global Interpreter Lock. If `worker` is CPU-intensive, threading won't speed it up - you'll need multiprocessing.

Comment: hi but i tried do that with multiprocessing but got stack with the memory share can you help with that?

Comment: depends on where exactly you got stuck. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: i used Pool thchnice but it still seem slow...

Comment: Does it "seem slow" or you have actual numbers which show that code with multiprocessing takes more time to finish the same task as single-threaded code?

Comment: i have the number.. it won't change look at the code i'd refreshed it to the multiprocessing  module can you see why the program won't run any faster??